# How to group and merge list of data using LINQ?

Tags: vb.net, linq, list

I have a list of data as shown below

**Original Data**

```
Genre   Name                       Year 
Comedy  Shrek Forever After        2010
Drama   The Karate Kid             2010
Action  Iron Man 2                 2010
Action  Robin Hood                 2010
Drama   The Kids Are All Right     2010
Sci-Fi  Inception                  2010
```

and I need to group the movies by Genre and concatenate similar movies name separated by "," so the new list looks like

**Required Data**

```
 Genre   Name                                     Year 
 Comedy  Shrek Forever After                      2010
 Drama   The Karate Kid, The Kids Are All Right   2010
 Action  Iron Man 2, Robin Hood                   2010
 Sci-Fi  Inception                                2010
```

The LINQ statement I wrote is as follows

```
Dim result = From p In movies Group p By p.Genre Into Group Select New Movie With {
         .Genre = Genre,
         .Name = String.Join(", ", Group.Select(Function(p) p.Name).ToArray()),
         .Year = Group.Select(Function(p) p.Year).FirstOrDefault
        }
```

**Is there another way of doing it so that I don't have to use ".Year = Group.Select(Function(p) p.Year).FirstOrDefault" or a different approach than mine.**

Thanks

Sample Code:

---

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim movies As New List(Of Movie)
        movies.Add(New Movie("Comedy", "Shrek Forever After", 2010))
        movies.Add(New Movie("Drama", "The Karate Kid", 2010))
        movies.Add(New Movie("Action", "Iron Man 2", 2010))
        movies.Add(New Movie("Action", "Robin Hood", 2010))
        movies.Add(New Movie("Drama", "The Kids Are All Right", 2010))
        movies.Add(New Movie("Sci-Fi", "Inception", 2010))

        'Group amd Merge by genre
        Dim result = From p In movies Group p By p.Genre Into Group Select New Movie With {
         .Genre = Genre,
         .Name = String.Join(", ", Group.Select(Function(p) p.Name).ToArray()),
         .Year = Group.Select(Function(p) p.Year).FirstOrDefault
        }

        For Each r In result
            Console.WriteLine(r)
        Next
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Public Class Movie
        Public Genre As String
        Public Name As String
        Public Year As Integer

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal genre As String, ByVal name As String, ByVal year As Integer)
            Me.Year = year
            Me.Genre = genre
            Me.Name = name
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return String.Format("Genre: {0}; Name:{1}; Year:{2}", Genre, Name, Year)
        End Function
    End Class

End Module
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure that the `Year` will never be null, which based on your class it shouldn't be, you could replace it with this:

```
.Year = Group.First().Year
```

However, I question your grouping approach. What happens when movies with the same genre don't share the same year? One might be 2009, another 2010, and you'll automatically take the first year. You could add an `OrderBy` to get the most recent year, but it all depends on your grouping intention.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the example I was using is just to get an idea and I was assuming year to be the same every time, so your suggestion works for me. Is the above LINQ query optimized for solving such problem. Any alternative suggestions?

Comment: @madan I think what you have fits your scenario well. If it groups everything as desired then I see no need to change it and your query is straightforward.